# Equivalence of two regularities of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \scr B , \mu)$ be a $\sigma-$ finite measure space, where $\scr B$ denotes Borel sigma algebra on topological space $X$. Suppose that for every $A\in \scr B$, we have $$\mu(A)=\inf\{ \mu(U): U\supset A \text{ is open.}\}=\sup\{\mu(F): F\subset A \text{ is closed}\} \tag 1$$

Consider the following statement: For every $\epsilon>0$, there exist open set $U$ and closed set $F$ such that $F\subset A\subset U$ and $\mu(U\setminus F)<\epsilon$. $\,\,\,\,\,(2)$

Are $(1)$ and $(2)$ equivalent?

$(1)\implies (2):$

If $\mu(A)<\infty$,then $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists U\supset A, F\subset A$ (open and closed resp.) such that $\mu(U)<\mu(A)+\epsilon/2, \mu(F)+\epsilon/2>\mu(A),$ whence the claim follows.  If $\mu(A)=\infty$, then writing $A$ as union $\bigcup_n A_n$ of finite measure sets (this is possible as $X$ is sigma finite), given $\epsilon>0$, there exist open set $U_n\supset A_n$ such that $\mu(U_n)<\mu(A_n)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},$ whence it follows that $\mu(U\setminus A)<\epsilon/2$, where $U=\bigcup_n U_n$ and $A=\bigcup_n A_n$. Similarly, $\exists V\supset A^c$ ($V$ is open) such that $\mu(V\setminus A^c)<\epsilon/2.$ It follows from these that $\mu(U\setminus V^c)<\epsilon$.  Hence this direction is proved.

For the other direction $(2)\implies (1)$:

It can be shown that $\mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(U): U\supset A\}$ for all Borel sets $A$. I'm stuck at showing that $\mu(A)= \sup\{ \mu(F):F\subset A \text{ is closed}\} $.

Comment: I think you reduce to the case of a finite measure and then use $\mu(X) - \mu(A^C) = \mu(A^C) = \inf\{\mu(U) : U \supset A^C\}$. At that point, $U^C \subset A$ is a closed set.

Comment: $\mu (A) \leq \mu (F)+\mu (A\setminus F) \leq \mu (F)+\mu (U\setminus F)\leq \mu (F)+\epsilon$

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)